Can the supremum involving the semi-norm $\|\bullet\|_{A}$ of $\Sigma_d({\mathbb R})$ be attained for $q$ arbitrarily large?
Let $d > 1$ be given. The Gelfand-Shilov space $\Sigma_d({\mathbb R})$ consists of those functions $f\in C^\infty({\mathbb R})$ with the property that
$$
 \|f\|_{A}:= \sup_{x\in {\mathbb R}}\sup_{n,q\in {\mathbb N}_0}\left(1+|x|\right)^q|f^{(n)}(x)|\frac{A^{n+q}}{n!^d q!^d} < \infty$$ for every $A> 0.$
It is not hard to see that the supremum above is in fact a maximum (depending on $f$).
My conjecture: given $A>0$ and $m>0$, there is a function $f\in \Sigma_d({\mathbb R})$ such that $$\|f\|_{A}= \sup_{x\in {\mathbb R}} \left(1+|x|\right)^q|f^{(n)}(x)|\frac{A^{n+q}}{n!^d q!^d}$$, with $q\geq m$.
Any idea how to prove or disprove such claim?
The most promising idea I had is to take a suitable $f\in \Sigma_d({\mathbb R})$, for instance $f(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and then consider the function $g(x):=f(\alpha x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and a suitable $0<\alpha<1$ depending on $m$. We have that $$\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{|x|^q|g^{(n)}(x)|\frac{A^{n+q}}{n!^d q!^d}\}=|\alpha|^{n-q} \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{|x|^q|f^{(n)}(x)|\frac{A^{n+q}}{n!^d q!^d}\}$$ for all $n, q$. But I don't know how to estimate the $\alpha$ that would shift in the desired way the q for which the supremum involved in $\|g\|_A$ is attained.

I have already solved the problem. The answer is yes and the idea I had outlined above works. If there is interest I may share the details.
